# Setting Cursor To The Beginning of QLineEdit With Inputmask In PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlineedit, cursor-position

I created a code for desktop software. That, In QLineEdit, I set an inputmask. When I run my program and clicked that lineedit, I saw my cursor position at the end of the line. Below is my some code....

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(380, 191)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 20, 211, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.lineEdit.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 110, 211, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.lineEdit_2.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.lineEdit_2.setInputMask("00.00")
        self.lineEdit_2.setCursorPosition(0)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I already mentioned that setCursorPosition(0) after that. But it does not works. I want that cursor at beginning of that lineedit when I click my lineEdit_2.

```
self.lineEdit_2.setInputMask("00.00")
self.lineEdit_2.setCursorPosition(0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install an event filter on the line edit and react to any mouse click event:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from ui_mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.lineEdit_2.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if source == self.lineEdit_2 and event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
            self.lineEdit_2.setFocus(QtCore.Qt.MouseFocusReason)
            self.lineEdit_2.setCursorPosition(0)
            return True
        return super().eventFilter(source, event)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

<sub>Note that you should write the above in a separate script which you'll use as your main program; the code you posted, taken from the output of `pyuic`, should *never* be modified. Read more about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).</sub>